# wasm index.html cant find assets in _content/ or _framework after MS Edge upgrade

Tags: .net, blazor

After upgrading MS Edge from v44 to v87 and no other code changes, my blazor project stopped downloading the wasm. It finds the index.html itself but I get 404 for any assets in _content/ or _framework/ which includes the blazor.webassembly.js-- so the process stops. I'm using hosted blazor/mvc and .net 5.

I can still browse to the css/ and other non-underscored files and I can hit the API server itself (mvc vs IIS express).

I've cleared the nuget cache with "dotnet nuget locals all --clear" and manually deleted all /bin and /obj folders with no luck.

This is also an issue with a newly generated project(s).  Like I said above; no code changes were made during the browser upgrade and I get similar errors with Firefox.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Perhaps a system-wide change happened- firewall, or your .net installation broke (try repairing it)

Comment: Turns out it was PROBABLY differences between VS and edge upgrades.. The original project was generated with VS 16.8.3 and worked with edge 44 but broke with edge 87-- but I'm currently on VS 16.8.4.  I regenerated the project with 16.8.4 and it now works with edge 87.  I noticed a lot of differences in the magic files but really don't have to time to research deeper. I moved my code to the new project and moving on.